# What's the time complexity of this method to find the number of inversions in an array (python)?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, time-complexity

```
inv=0
for j in range(n):
     inv=inv+ sum((x<arr[j]) for x in arr[j:] )
```

For every element I am checking the number of elements smaller than it occurring after it in the array.(**arr[j : ]**)

Comment: Should be O(n^2) with your logic since there are two loops used.

Comment: @SunilA What about the logic? Is it efficient or is there any other method?

Comment: Sort the array in `O(n*log(n))` then the number of inversions in `0`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is **O(n<sup>2</sup>)**. Here is how you can compute this:

- for the 1<sup>st</sup> element, you need to compare with the next n-1 elements.
- for the 2<sup>nd</sup> element, you need to compare with the next n-2 elements.

  ...
- for the n<sup>th</sup> element, you need to compare with the next 0 elements.

Therefore, in total you are making (n-1) + (n-2) + ... + 1 + 0 = n(n-1) / 2 comparisons, which is quadratic in n.

---

More efficient approaches do exist. For example, by using a **divide and conquer** based strategy, you can count them in **O(n log(n))**. See [this nice link](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/counting-inversions/)!

Answer (score 0):

```
inv=0
for j in range(n):
    inv=inv+ sum((x<arr[j]) for x in arr[j:] )
```

Let's break this code into three parts

**1:** `inv = 0`
This will take contant time operation sat `T1`

**2:** `for j in range(n):`
here we are running a loop for variable `n`

total time required now is `T1 + N * f(a)` here `f(a)` is the time taken by the body of loop. For simplicity we can remove constant factor. So complexity is `N * f(a)`

Now here comes the tricky part. What is f(a)

**3:** `inv = inv + sum((x<arr[j]) for x in arr[j:] )`
concentrate on `sum((x < arr[j] for x in arr[j:])`
sum will add all the values that are below `arr[j]` in

**loop** `for x in arr[j:]`

so you are left with f(a) as `N`, `N - 1`, `N - 2` up to `N - N`

Combining this all together you get `N * (N + N - 1 + N - 2 + ... + N - N)` which is `(N * N - 1) / 2` that is `O(N^2)`

Hope you get it.